# python combining two logics of map()

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

In my code, the function `f(a,b)` for `map()` takes two 1x3 numpy array as input. Since it's someone else's implementation from C code, I cannot change `f()`.

The second input `y` is always a Nx3 numpy array. The first input `x` has two cases.

In one case, it is a 1x3 numpy array, thus I do

```
unwrap = partial(f, x)
result = map(unwrap, y)
```

In the other case, it is a Nx3 numpy array, then I do

```
unwrap = f
result = map(unwrap, x, y)
```

Is there a way to combine the two cases together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.broadcast_to` can 'reshape' `A` to match `B`; then you can iterate over the two together.  It uses striding, so there's not actual increase in memory use.

```
In [370]: def f(a,b):
     ...:     assert(a.shape==(1,3))
     ...:     assert(b.shape==(1,3))
     ...:     return a+b
     ...: 
In [371]: B=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [372]: A=np.arange(3).reshape(1,3)
In [373]: np.broadcast_to(A, B.shape)   # (1,3) to (4,3)
Out[373]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
In [374]: np.broadcast_to(B, B.shape)   # no change with (4,3)
Out[374]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

I usually use list comprehensions rather than map:

```
In [375]: [f(np.atleast_2d(a),np.atleast_2d(b)) for a,b in zip(np.broadcast_to(A,B.shape),B)]
Out[375]: 
[array([[0, 2, 4]]),
 array([[3, 5, 7]]),
 array([[ 6,  8, 10]]),
 array([[ 9, 11, 13]])]

In [376]: [f(np.atleast_2d(a),np.atleast_2d(b)) for a,b in zip(np.broadcast_to(B,B.shape),B)]
Out[376]: 
[array([[0, 2, 4]]),
 array([[ 6,  8, 10]]),
 array([[12, 14, 16]]),
 array([[18, 20, 22]])]
```

Iteration over the 2d arrays produces a list of 1d arrays, hence the need for `np.atleast_2d` to satisfy my `f` assertions.  I won't need that if `f` accepted (3,) inputs as well.

Or with `map`:

```
In [377]: map(lambda a,b: f(np.atleast_2d(a),np.atleast_2d(b)), np.broadcast_to(B,B.shape),B)
Out[377]: <map at 0xb14f4c6c>
In [378]: list(_)
Out[378]: 
[array([[0, 2, 4]]),
 array([[ 6,  8, 10]]),
 array([[12, 14, 16]]),
 array([[18, 20, 22]])]
In [379]: map(lambda a,b: f(np.atleast_2d(a),np.atleast_2d(b)), np.broadcast_to(A,B.shape),B)
Out[379]: <map at 0xb0871a8c>
In [380]: list(_)
Out[380]: 
[array([[0, 2, 4]]),
 array([[3, 5, 7]]),
 array([[ 6,  8, 10]]),
 array([[ 9, 11, 13]])]
```

`np.vectorize` and `np.frompyfunc` handle this kind of broadcasting as well, but they are designed for functions that take scalars, not 1d arrays.

With `broadcast_arrays` I can treat both arrays equally:

```
In [386]: map(lambda a,b: f(np.atleast_2d(a),np.atleast_2d(b)), *np.broadcast_arrays(B,A))
Out[386]: <map at 0xb69851ac>
In [387]: list(_)
Out[387]: 
[array([[0, 2, 4]]),
 array([[3, 5, 7]]),
 array([[ 6,  8, 10]]),
 array([[ 9, 11, 13]])]
```

More generally, `A` and `B` can be anything that produces the required `(N,3)` arrays.  And I can get rid of the `atleast_2d` use by producing `(N,1,3)` arrays:

```
In [397]: map(f, *np.broadcast_arrays(np.arange(3)[None,None,:], np.arange(0,40,10)[:,None,None]))
Out[397]: <map at 0xb08b562c>
In [398]: list(_)
Out[398]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2]]),
 array([[10, 11, 12]]),
 array([[20, 21, 22]]),
 array([[30, 31, 32]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you're zipping `x` and `y` together and passing it to `f`. In the first case, you're applying `f` to `x` and mapping it over `y` - in other words you're applying `f` to a constant argument and a variable one.

So you should be able to see that applying `f` to a constant argument is the same as mapping it over a constant list. In particular,

```
map(partial(f, x), y) == map(f, [x]*len(y), y)
```

> **Aside**: Haskellers will recognise this as one of the *applicative laws*:
>
> ```
> pure (f x) = fmap f (pure x)
> ```

While they behave the same, they don't have quite the same characteristics. I'd expect the second to allocate more memory and take longer to run. But that's firmly in the realm of micro-optimisations; unless you've profiled it and determined that you really need this code to be as fast as humanly possible, it's better to go for the cleaner option.